# Анонимные параметры в С++

Tags: c++, функции, параметры

Заметил, что если сделать анонимный параметр, компилятор не будет ругаться на это.

Например

```
void func(int) { return; }
```

не вызовет никаких проблем.

Только не нашёл ничего насчёт этого в инете. Может, ищу не так. Зачем это и как такое кушать? Или где можно об этом почитать? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если аргумент не нужен и если компилятор расценивает неиспользуемые переменные как ошибку, то программа не скомпилируется. В этом случае его можно сделать анонимным.

Answer (score 3):

Просто бывает, что такой аргумент не нужен.

Ну, например, какая-нибудь библиотечная функция, которая принимает в качестве параметра функцию от двух переменных. А вам она не нужна - у вас один параметр, второй не нужен. Не используется.

И что делать? можно, конечно, написать функцию от двух аргументов - и не использовать второй. Но тогда компилятор удивится :)

Есть, конечно, и другие пути обхода этого предупреждения, например,

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
    (void)b;
    return 2*a;
}
```

или

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4100 )
int f(int a, int b)
{
    return 2*a;
}
#pragma warning( pop )
```

в Visual C++.

Но самое простое - просто указать тип параметра без его имени...

Comment: Или, частенько, при наследовании встречается. Бывает что в родителе или наследнике некоторые параметры метода не нужны.

Answer (score 3):

Это один из многих атавизмов из С (или даже из B). В нем реализован крайне вальготный подход к объявлению / определению функций, в т.ч.:

- объявление функции вообще без параметров и затем указание произвольных аргументов при определении (это в С++ к счатью запретили)
- несоответствие const квалификаторов аргументов при объявлении и определении
- несоответствие имен аргументов при объявлении и определении

Даже в самом C нет никаких причин прибегать к подобным трюкачествам, и зачастую все несоответствия подобного рода, в т.ч. опущенные имена аргументов классифицируются как дефект. Также типичной ошибкой является пропуск имени аргумента для подавления предупреждения о неиспользуемом аргументе. Наличие неиспользуемых аргументов также может классифицироваться как дефект, но для явного указания, что аргумент не будет использован предусмотрен стандартный (с С++17) аттрибут `[[maybe_unused]]`:

```
void func([[maybe_unused]] int const value) { return; }
```

Comment: Атавизмы С? Но С **запрещает** и всегда запрещал использование неименованных параметорв в определениях функций. А в вопросе речь идет именно об определении.

Comment: @AnT Долгое время С вообще мало чего запрещал, а как такое ограничение позже угодило в стандарт - это на самом деле интересный вопрос. Ну а если собирать современным конформным компилятором, то да, будет ругаться.

Comment: К данному случаю это не относится, ибо "долгое время" в С вообще не было синтаксиса определения "с прототипом", а существовал только K&R синтаксис объявления и определения функций. Именно во избежание неоднозначности между этими двумя вариантами в рамках определения функции в С никогда не было возможности указывать безымянные параметры. То есть это не "запрет" как таковой, а просто изначальное принципиальное отсутствие такой возможности.